# Text is under the button in the texarea

Tags: html, css, textarea

I have a textarea and a button placed on top right. When text reaches button position it stays under it. I need text to "avoid" this button. I would appreciate any help! Thanks!
Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4klS.png

This is HTML:

```
<div id="textarea-container">
  <md-input-container class="md-block">
    <textarea id="expandable" rows="3" cols="150"></textarea>
    <md-button id="textarea-button" class="md-raised"></md-button>    
  </md-input-container>
</div>
```

This is CSS:

```
#textarea-container textarea {
height: 4em!important;
transition: all 0.5s ease!important;
box-sizing: border-box;
overflow-y: auto;
resize: none;
}

#textarea-container {
position: relative;
}
#textarea-button {
position: absolute;
top: 3px;
right: 0;
}
```

Comment: What about giving a nice right padding to the textarea?

Comment: @Teemoh I forgot to mention that on click , text area expands, so padding brings not expected solution

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you wrap md-input container and md-button with layout="row", and remove the CSS to textarea-button.

```
    <div id="textarea-container" layout="row">
      <md-input-container class="md-block">
          <textarea id="expandable" rows="3" cols="150"></textarea>    
      </md-input-container>
    <md-button id="textarea-button" class="md-raised"></md-button>  
    </div>

#textarea-button {
//remove CSS
}
```

working jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/cg1e9yy1/
you can now go from here.

Comment: I know this works, but unfortunately I Need to have this button to like like it belongs to the textarea